# Filling an IFRAME with dynamic content from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamic-content

I have an IFRAME that should be filled with content from JavaScript. Had the content be on the server all I had to do is:

```
    function onIFrameFill() {
         myIframe.location.href = "HelloWorld.html";
     }
```

But the content I have is a HTML page generated on the client and represented as a string (I have not much influence on it). How can I populate the content of the my iframe programatically?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
var iframeDoc = myIframe.contentWindow.document;
iframeDoc.open();
iframeDoc.write('hello world');
iframeDoc.close();
```

Comment: For me in Chrome Version 41.0.2272.76 m if you don't open() the iframeDoc first, then it will *append* the text; if you open() it clears out the iframeDoc and *overwrites* the text. You can write('<em>bold</em>') and the HTML will be interpreted as a tag.

Comment: What about Chrome complaining about document.write()?
[Violation] Avoid using document.write(). https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write
This seems like a legitimate use, since I'm not injecting scripts. Still it would be nice not to have "Violation" appear in the console

Comment: @BrianK Using `document.write()` isn’t recommended for performance reasons. I believe I gave this answer because it most directly addressed OP’s question. It would be better to set `iframe.contentWindow.location.href` to a page and then have that page make DOM changes.

Answer (score 4):

Tried setting  `.innerHTML`  but that does not work. Solution by Jeffery To works. Just want to add that  `myIframe.contentWindow`  might not work in old browsers (read IE old versions) so you can do

```
var iFrameWindow = myIframe.contentWindow || myIframe.documentWindow;
var iFrameDoc = iFrameWindow.document;
```

then use the document open(), write() & close() as above.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Jeffry but using `contentDocument` instead.

```js
let iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
let doc = iframe.contentDocument;
doc.open();
doc.write('Hello world!');
doc.close();
```

Comment: Instead of `document.write()` you could now use a new attribute on iframe which is srcDoc. https://caniuse.com/iframe-srcdoc

Answer (score 0):

What about `.innerHTML`?

```
myIframe.innerHTML = "This is some HTML <b>text</b>";
```