# Is it possible to make a link from my website go to the middle of the page on an outside website?

Tags: html, hyperlink, web

I am attempting to link from my website to an outside website but the information that relates to the user is in the middle of the outside page. Can I make the link take them to there?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Only if that page provides an anchor you can link to (e.g. `somesite.com/somepage.html#anchor`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that outside page has an anchor tag in or near the content you wish to link to, yes.

`<a name="releventContent">`

If the above code (or something like it) is present in the outside page, you can link to it from your site like so:

`<a href="http://www.outsidepage.com#releventContent">clicky</a>`

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you a dirty trick that might work or not too. Steps

1. Open the new link in an IFrame.
2. Create a javascript function that will accept the string to search as parameter.
3. On the bodyload call that function that will search for the text in the source file.

Some SO links

[Filling an IFRAME with dynamic content from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665980/filling-an-iframe-with-dynamic-content-from-javascript)

[Read IFrame content using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777316/read-iframe-content-using-javascript)

Comment: That is a good idea but I am very limited in what my CMS allows me to do with javascript but ill remember that.

Comment: anyways vote up and accept the answer that helped you. It will be appreciated.