# iframe append to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gongzhitaao/WZ84a/).

When I execute

```
$('body').append('helo')
```

**inside** `iframe`, the string was appended to the parent.

How can I avoid this behaviour **without changing** the script inside the `iframe`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does appending a <script> to a dynamically created <iframe> seem to run the script in the parent page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591135/why-does-appending-a-script-to-a-dynamically-created-iframe-seem-to-run-the)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help others,  please refer to the following answers:

[Why does appending a  to a dynamically created  seem to run the script in the parent page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591135/why-does-appending-a-script-to-a-dynamically-created-iframe-seem-to-run-the)

It works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

[http://jsfiddle.net/WZ84a/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/WZ84a/2/)

but it is not easy.
i have found another [source here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665980/filling-an-iframe-with-dynamic-content-from-javascript)

```
<iframe id="demo"></iframe>

var frame = document.getElementById("demo");
var html = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' +encodeURI('<body>Hello</body>');
frame.src = html;
```

I would personally use DIVs as it is very good and useful, can do everything an iFrame can do and more (Yes, maybe there is something that i do not know of, but nothing which I use in my everyday web development life!). iFrames is old and poor

**EDIT:**
Just found [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandy98/dWpvf/), Problem solved

Comment: Thanks.  But what about scripts?  `$('#demo').contents().find('body').append('helo');` works too.  But when it's comes to script, the string is always appended to the parent.

Comment: @gongzhitaao the thing is about iFrames, you don't always have control over them for security reasons, you can however call javascript in the parent from within the iFrame.

Comment: I still don't see the point.  I want to use js to **dynamically** add content to iframe, not static content.  I know how to do it in the static way as I've shown in my previous comment.