# How to inject component on iframe in angular4 project?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

My goal is to show my components on multiple layout (using media queries - Small, Medium, Large) inside my style guide. The only way I can think of is using `iframe` since using HTML elements won't work with media queries.

How can I achieve this? I am also open to any suggestions (as in, non `iframe` approach).

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665980/filling-an-iframe-with-dynamic-content-from-javascript?

Comment: No. The solution is too simple for what I want. I want a good robust solution on Angular(4). Thanks tho!

Comment: use bypasssafehtml function from domsanitize api from angualr and create an implementation of component. angular blocks iframe by default if i am not mistaken